# Adding Random and Non-Recurring Numbers to an Array

Tags: c#

How can I add numbers to an array such that each new number is random and non-recurring?

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int NUM_ROWS = 5;
        const int NUM_COLS = 7;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
            RandInt randNumbers = new RandInt(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
            int count = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
            {
                List<int> newRow = new List<int>();
                matrix.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
                {
                    newRow.Add(RandInt.numbers[count++].number);
                }
            }
        }
        public class RandInt
        {
            public static List<RandInt> numbers = new List<RandInt>();
            public int number { get; set; }
            public int rand { get; set; }

            public RandInt() { }

            public RandInt(int SIZE)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    numbers.Add(new RandInt() { number = i, rand = r.Next()}); 
                }
                numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x.rand).ToList();
            }
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: ...And the question is?...

Comment: surely you don't mean [The Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix)?

Comment: To get non-recurring number make an array like 1 to 100.  Then randomize the array.  Easiest way to do this is to create a class with two objects 1) int number 2) int randNumber.  add random number of 2nd object then randomize the class by random number.  The first object number will get randomized.

Comment: Random r = new Random();
    int number = rnd.Next(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 100

Comment: Looks like good first line of a post. Now please add what you tried and what problem you have implementing the code. You can also consider using search engine of your choice to find similar posts. I.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+unique+random+array (so far amount of research and efforts shown in the post will likely invite downvotes)

Comment: yea i mean array sory

Comment: While this is a bad question as it stands (given that it isn't a question), it was easy for me to edit it such that it is a legitimate question with a specific answer. My edit won't show up until it is peer reviewed, but I am posting an answer to my edited version because I think it deserves to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate random numbers by using the built in `Random` class, and use the array function `Contains` to check if the number generated is already in the array. In my example below I generate a new numbers until I find one that isn't in the array yet, then add it.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] intArray = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int next = 0;
    while (intArray.Contains(next = rand.Next())) { }
    intArray[i] = next;
}
```

Note: One drawback to this approach is that it is potentially non-terminating because it could infinitely produce the same numbers over and over that are already in the array. However, for most applications of this sort of thing I doubt it would be an issue.